# IRC clients with DCC support

Tags: software-recommendation, irc

I need an IRC client with DCC support. What are my options? Additionally, is there a way to patch DCC support into Empathy? I would prefer patching as opposed to installing a seperate program.

Comment: Empathy is a libpurple implementation like pidgin.  AFAIK, pidgin or empathy does have limited DCC support to at least send files. Perhaps try pidgin instead? It's practically the same thing..

Comment: @user606723, if Pigdin is virtually the same thing, then I see no reason to bother with it. I just want the ability to recieve files.

Comment: Err, as I said both pidgin and empathy should be able to send/receive files. I've never used empathy, but I know pidgin can receive files. Are you sure it's empathy thats the issue and not a firewall, etc. issue? I suggested you try pidgin just in case it was broken in empathy for an unknown reason.

Answer (score 4):

Nearly every IRC client supports (at least partial) DCC.

Here are my picks from linux clients-

1. irssi
2. x-chat

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_clients#Direct_Client-to-Client_.28DCC.29_support